# Wireshark - SACK_PERM=1

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

We are capturing a file transfer from machine 1 to machine 2 via Wireshark. While I am unable to capture any/few retransmission errors, other guy is able to capture around 10 to 15 retransmission errors and underrun errors.

On analysing the wire-shark capture, I find that the major difference is that `SACK_PERM` flag is not set in my capture, whereas `SACK_PERM=1` in other capture.

Below is

`8535   7.272671    172.23.165.254  10.108.32.29    TCP 62` [TCP Retransmission] `29537 → 389 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1`

Can anyone explain the effects of `SACK_PERM` `flag` in a network transmission?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the "Sack-Permitted" option from [RFC 2018](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2018), "TCP Selective Acknowledgment Options".  It says that the two machines can use "selective acknowledgment", meaning that, instead of just saying "I got all bytes up to this sequence number", they can say "I got all the bytes in this range and all the bytes in this other range", with the implication being that bytes in ranges not listed were *not* received, so that they can say that they got bytes before and after some ranges, but not the bytes in the middle of the range.

Comment: Yes.  SACK is used in high-packet-loss situations to allow a machine to only request the information that's missing, whereas without SACK, you get anything from the first missing packet until the current period.  It's not useful in LAN situations or very reliable networks.